# Issue of precision when coding discrete distribution in c

Tags: c, algorithm, probability, probability-distribution

I am relatively new to C and so when it comes to issues of precision I am always a bit worried. I am working with a rather larger code and at a specific point I need to select a value based off of a discrete probability distribution. Essentially what I need to do is select a value k=1,2,...N with probabilities given by the formula

P(k) = [e<sup>a*F(k)</sup>]/[Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>e<sup>aF(i)</sup>],

where F is just some function that uses k as an input and a is a real number. [Sorry the formula looks rough I wasn't sure how to format it.] My code looks (roughly) like this so far. I've had to make some changes to aid readability out of context.

```
int k;
int N=10;
double a=5.5; //In the code it is just a positive real number
double xtemp=0;
double X[10];
double fk;

for(k=0;k<N;k++){
  fk = F(k); // Here F returns a double
  xtemp += exp(a*fk);
  X[k]=xtemp;
}
xtemp = xtemp*U01(); //U01 returns a uniformly random number on [0,1]
for(k=0;k<K;k++){
   if(xtemp<=X[k]){
     return k;
   }
}
```

This should give the desired result from a mathematical perspective, however someone better at coding than me said the xtemp could become problematic and become imprecise. I was wondering how you could do error handling for this? I'd also be open to a better way to implement the idea. I appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: What are the individual `exp(a*F(k))` values like? Are they very big? Very small? Are they a mixture of very big and very small? The last one is most likely to cause precision issues ...

Comment: This might help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Comment: @Useless The values vary a good bit, and can end up being rather large. I'd say that typically 1<a<20 and .25<F(k)<36, which means rough worst case scenario for the last entry would be N*exp(720). Since all these terms are positive I was thinking of making some of the doubles unsigned. That should help right?

Comment: @Scot Have you tried to see whether `exp(720)` is even different from `INFINITY` in your C implementation?

Comment: `exp(720)` is way too big for a `double` but apparently `long double` should be able to handle it.

Comment: @EOF I have tried it and it registers `exp(720)` as infinity.

Comment: @Scot I'd say that confirms that the code you have provided is *not* acceptable.

Comment: Unsigned doubles are not a thing, btw, and one bit wouldn't make that much of a difference anyway

Comment: Oh, and since you're trying to store the cdf values in your array, have you tried just calculating this in python (or something else with bignums) ahead of time, and seeing if you can scale the values back down while keeping the proportions?

Comment: To match the formula I'd expect `F(k+1);`

Comment: @Patrick87 There is no guarantee `long double` can represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your current code could cause evaluation of sub-expressions that fall outside of the finite range of representable values for `double`, I'd recommend rewriting the expression. Consider something like this:

P(k) = [e<sup>a*F(k)</sup>]/[Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>e<sup>a * F(i)</sup>]

P<sup>-1</sup>(k) = [Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>e<sup>a * F(i)</sup>]
/ [e<sup>a*F(k)</sup>]

P<sup>-1</sup>(k) = Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>[e<sup>a * F(i)</sup>
/ e<sup>a*F(k)</sup>]

P<sup>-1</sup>(k) = Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>[e<sup>a * F(i) - a * F(k)</sup>]

P<sup>-1</sup>(k) = Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>[e<sup>a * (F(i) - F(k))</sup>]

P(k) = [Σ<sub>i=1,...,N</sub>[e<sup>a * (F(i) - F(k))</sup>]]<sup>-1</sup>

If you could provide a minimal, complete and testable example, you could probably get considerably better advice.